# ag-grid copy to clipboard with formatting/styles feature

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I want to copy data of ag-grid to clipboard with formatting. 
I am able to copy the data without format/style.

Is the feature available in ag-grid so that i can copy format of data as well.
I am trying this in ag-grid(angular) to paste the date to excel.

Best Regards,
Kaleem

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to being able to copy the value with "html style and formatting" this is not possible in agGrid, and wouldn't necessarily be useful as you would be pasting HTML code into Excel.

You can read here for how to achieve Excel styling on export: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/

You can use the gridOptions method **processCellForClipboard** to prepare the data itself however you want for export.

However, if like me you desired to simply get access to the data from the column's ValueFormatter, below is the only way I was able to achieve this:

```
processCellForClipboard = (params: ProcessCellForExportParams) => {

        let colDef:ColDef = params.column.getColDef();
        if (colDef.valueFormatter){
            return colDef.valueFormatter({
                ...params,
                data: params.node?.data,
                colDef: colDef
            } as ValueFormatterParams);
        }

        return params.value;
 };
```

The idea is, use the ValueFormatter to format the value as you want it displayed in the grid. This way, you can at least get the value formatted into a proper string when copying it from the grid.

Cheers

Comment: Hey! I am getting error for this solution. Error is:-----

(property) ColDef.valueFormatter?: I ((params: ValueFormatterParams) ) A function to format a value, should return a string. Not used for CSV export or copy to clipboard, only for UI cell rendering. TS2349: (TS) This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string I ((params: ValueFormatterParams) => string)' are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures.

Comment: Nvm, It worked. I had to make colDef "any" instead of "ColDef". Not sure why! ------
let colDef: any = params.column.getColDef();

Comment: In case anyone still gets this and using typescript
you should check if the valueFormatter is a function
`if(typeof coldDef.valueFormatter === 'function') { ....`